# How to throttle a mousemove event in RxJs when using angular 2 + Typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular, stream, rxjs

I'm in the process of learning RxJs. I use Angular2 rc3.
The following stream works, but it gives me **too many mousemove events**. I want to slow them down using time(throttling) or another control stream. 
How can i do that?

Mouse move Stream without throttling

```
const mouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, 'mousemove');

mouseMove$.subscribe( x => console.log(x)); // works great, many {mouse position object} 's
```

Simple solution: Using throttling should be something like this:

```
const mouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, 'mousemove');
const latestMouseEventEvery1Second$ = mouseMove$.sample(1000);

latestMouseEventEvery1Second$.subscribe( x => console.log(x)); // error
```

- this **sample() operator** i've taken form here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html

But this does not work in angular 2 - CLI project.
Gives me this error:

```
***Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<\any>'*** - notice i've put <\MouseEvent> when casting.
```

**Another more powerful way to achieve the same result, i think can be the flowing:**
It will be great if we can send the latest `mousemove item` **based on the items received from another stream**. Any stream - created by us..

For example:

When we receive a new item(1, 2,3..) from the `eachSecond$` Stream ( = our "Control Stream"), - we emit donwstream (into the `mouseMoveEachSecond$`) - the latest item received from `mouseMove$` stream.

```
const eachSecond$ = Observable.timer(0, 1000); // starts at 0 and gives 1,2,3 as values each 1000 milliseconds.
const mouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, 'mousemove');

const mouseMoveEachSecond$ = Observable.merge(eachSecond$,mouseMove$)
  .some magic operator I can't find()
  // this could work like this:
    // many mouse items are coming at a high rate from the mouse stream
    // only a few items (1,2,3..) are coming form the eachSecond$ stream
    //the logic: We send downstream **only one mouse item** (the last) for each new item that is coming form the eachSecond$ stream.
);

mouseMoveEachSecond$.subscribe( x => console.log(x)); 
// a { mouse position object } = mouse item - only when you move the mouse 
// and no more than one {mouse position object} per second}
```

Sound's simple. I found this particularly hard to implement - form what i can tell, this is because  the state of the stream should be shared somehow. A way to tell what was already been sent is needed..

In the mouseMoveEachSecond$ the items are coming one by one, in sequence. Or a number or an object. You need to know:

- Which was the last `time item` when you receive a new `mouse item`.
- And which was the last `mouse item` when you receive a new `time item`.

This will enables you to:

- not send a `mouse item` downstream when the mouse doesn't move on the screen.
- not send a `mouse item` downstream while there is no new `time item` released form the eachSecond$ stream.

This can be done using global variables. But is not the RxJS way of doing things.. I don't know of a way to store the last sent item and use it in the next step. Reduce operator can keep the state:  from one item released - to another, but how we can use that property to achieve this behavior? This streams must be considered infinite. Hmm... should be simpler way to combine this 2 streams.. Maybe is too early.. I feel that my brain doesn't want to think in Streams :)

So the 2 questions laid clear:

1. which are some ways to throttle a mousemove Stream in angular 2?
2. can i use another stream to control when i release the mousemove items? If yes, this "Control Stream" can be any stream, or there are limitations?

Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are so very close! Ironically your magic operator *is* `sample`.

The old variant of sample (from RxJS4) was overloaded and could take a number as its argument. In RxJS5 (the one that ships with Angular2) it has been split so that there are actually two operators `sample` and `sampleTime`. The latter is the one takes a time argument and takes the last event in a given time window when it emits.

```
const mouseMoveEachSecond$ = mouseMove$.sampleTime(1000);
```

The former takes an `Observable` as its only argument and emits the last item received each time the control `Observable` emits.

i.e.

```
const eachSecond$ = Observable.timer(0, 1000); // starts at 0 and gives 1,2,3 as values each 1000 milliseconds.
const mouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, 'mousemove');

const mouseMoveEachSecond$ = mouseMove$.sample(eachSecond$);

mouseMoveEachSecond$.subscribe( x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Genius answer man, thank you ! - i lost more than 5 hours trying to do this - using scan operator - keeping the states between emits, all of that. I'm so glad it is so simple. Do you know a quick way to expand this to multiple control streams?  Like when you wait for multiple promises to complete before doing something?

Comment: No problem! And you could look at combining the control streams using `zip` or `forkJoin`, so that they only emit when there is a value for each stream.

Answer (score 0):

what about importing throttleTime:

```
import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and then use it as such:

```
mousemouve$.pipe(
      throttleTime(5000)
    )
```